# How to display "No result found" message if query result is empty in ng-tags-input?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-tags-input

Here is my code. If loadTags returns empty result then is there any way to show no result found message?

```
 <tags-input ng-model="tags" on-invalid-tag='test'
 display-property="Name" add-from-autocomplete-only="true" 
 tabindex="3"> 

 <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>

 </tags-input>
```

Comment: Can you bulid jsfiddle

Comment: ok i'll, for now i try to explain my problem - When i search something in ng-input-tag and no record exists in database then in this condition a message should display ie "no record found" but nothing is happening right now. Like that: http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285679/angular-ngfor-ngif-condition-in-data-filtering-by-pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285679/angular-ngfor-ngif-condition-in-data-filtering-by-pipe) This may hel you if you are using pipes with angular2+

Answer (score -2):

I dont know what api/data(Array) your using we have to using ng-show in ng-repeat to show show "No result found" tag in html here is the code

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $filter)
{ $scope.nodata = false;   
    $scope.items = [
        {id:1, name:'John'},
        {id:2, name:'Steve'},
        {id:3, name:'Joey'},
        {id:4, name:'Mary'},
        {id:5, name:'Marylin'}];

    $scope.items2 = $scope.items;

    $scope.$watch('search', function(val)
    { 
        console.log($filter('filter')($scope.items2, val));
        $scope.items = $filter('filter')($scope.items2, val); // items return for api after search if array is empty
        if($filter('filter')($scope.items2, val).length == 0){ // item are empty
           $scope.nodata = true;
        }
        else{
          $scope.nodata = false;   
        }
    });
};
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="search">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <div ng-show="nodata">NO results found</div>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
.no_rocord{border-color: #ececec;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-radius: 2px;
width: 250px;
padding: 6px;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 9999;
position: absolute;
margin-top: -6px;
background-color: #ffffff
}
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/4DVHUyLmXAnTKVIMzmAT?p=preview)

Comment: thanks pavanAstechie, i am using ng-tag-input directive in which tags has been selected from drop down, you can view the example over here http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/bDx54d/preview
When we type something in searchbox if it doesn't match then "no record found" should be displayed

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/JTh1n7lmLqyEKHlfpds8?p=preview is it ok for you,if ok please let me now i will update my answer so it will be helpful to others

Comment: If not i will try other solution waiting for you

Comment: Yes @PavanAsTechie it works, it would be much better if we will have some thing like that   http://ghiden.github.io/angucomplete-alt/  search here something, no result found message will be shown in dropdown

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/4DVHUyLmXAnTKVIMzmAT?p=preview  Find a solution. We can manage it from CSS, now it works almost like i want :) .

Comment: its good but "no result found" should not be selected as a tag.   please check it once

Comment: If you reached your solution i will update my answer with desired solution Please give me up vote