# Angular ngFor ngIF condition in data filtering by pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, pipe, ngfor

ngFor filtering based on a search using pipe - This is working fine ,

Now I have to add ngIf condition  based on the search query

If nothing result then I have to show another new div with 'no data' text

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="queryString" placeholder="Search to type">

<li *ngFor="let project of projects | FilterPipe: queryString ;>
{{project.project_name}} 
</li>
```

//pipe

```
transform(value: any, input:any ): any {
    if(input){
      input = input.toLowerCase();
      return value.filter(function (el: any) {
        return el.project_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1;
      })
    }
    return value;
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the results of the `filter` pipe in the template, you can create a local variable with the help of the `as` keyword.

```
<li *ngFor="let project of (projects | FilterPipe: queryString) as results">
  {{project.project_name}} 
</li>
```

Now you can access the results from your filter pipe in the `results` variable. But the scope of this local variable is now limited to the hosting HTML element and its children. We can fix this by rewriting your code a little.

```
<ul *ngIf="(projects | FilterPipe: searchQuery) as results">
  <li *ngFor="let project of results">
    {{project.project_name}} 
  </li>
  <span *ngIf="results.length === 0">No data</span>
</ul>
```

This way we have expanded the scope of the `results` variable and we can easily use it to display `No Data` when the filtered dataset is empty.

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-fitler-pipe).